# Azure Websites - new deployment of a PHP app with Composer fails

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

A deployment of a new PHP app fails with Composer, in the deployment logs, that are located in

```
D:\home\site\deployments\long-alphanumerical-string\log.log
```

I see the following:

```
Could not open input file: D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Commands\\composer.phar,,0
```

The same setup works on other environments of the application without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if the Composer extension is added on the Extensions blade
2. It's possible that your composer installation didn't work well. Check if the mentioned file exists, if it doesn't - get it from https://getcomposer.org/download/  (phar files are at the bottom of the page), upload it via kudu and Redeploy the application.